# Batch commands execution order

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm looking to run a second batch command from .bat but after the first command has been done.

```
REN "myfile.txt" "my_file.txt"
start "title" "path"
```

Here, I want the rename command to be executed before the process I wanted to start that has been terminated or executed. why it doesn't work in sequence order?

**Update:**

Both commands work correctly in order if I put a 'pause' or /sleep between the commands.

Comment: What leads you to believe the commands aren't being executed in order?  Are you seeing output that implies otherwise?  It just possible that the rename command isn't working as you'd expect?

Comment: Rename command is working but after the start process command.

Comment: It should work as you describe; can you post a test case that shows that it doesn't? Try changing your start to "start cmd /c dir path\my*.*"

Comment: If you have anti-virus software, disable it and see if it then works as expected.  AV can interfere with file operations.

Comment: @sean: You should either get an error or a wait until completion in any case.

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, there should be an error.  Also, this batch file should work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `REN` command in a separate batch file--I think `CALL` may force the batch to wait until it returns:

-- file1.bat

```
CALL file2.bat "myfile.txt" "my_file.txt"
start "title" "path"
```

-- file2.bat

```
REN %1 %2
```